# Problem with Winbind/Samba

Tags: samba, users, dns

I've been having an issue on my network that has completely vexed me.

I have three workstations running Ubuntu 13.04, one Windows 7 workstation, and three servers on Ubuntu Server 12.04. One of the servers is a domain controller running Samba4 and handles DNS, Kerberos, NTP, and DHCP.

Today I was trying to add a laptop to the domain, running Ubuntu 13.10. I issue `net ads join -U AdminUser` and the laptop joins the domain with no errors. I literally copied and pasted the config files from the other workstations and verified the permissions.

When I run `wbinfo` I can see the domain users and groups. However, when I run `getent` I see only local users and groups. If I run `wbinfo -a domainuser --verbose`, I am asked for the user's password and the password is accepted with no errors. Kerberos works as well.

`nsswitch.conf`, `pam.d/common-auth`, `pam.d/common-session`, `pam.d/common-account`, `smb.conf`, and `krb5.conf` are all exact copies of the other systems (which work), and I've even read through them all to verify this.

Is there something I've overlooked?

Is there something that was changed on Ubuntu between 13.04 and 13.10?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never could figure out the problem, so I wound up removing Ubuntu and installing Ubuntu 13.04 instead of 13.10.

I followed the exact same procedures as before everything now works like a charm.

Never could find anything in the logs that indicated a problem, so I don't know if this was due to a bug or what.

At any rate, I'm up and running now. Thank you anyway!

Comment: This is not really a solution, just a workaround.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and installing `libnss-winbind` resolved the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install libnss-winbind
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so much for this! I have been struggeling with this 'last piece of the puzzle' for 4 days now, with endless reinstalls and startovers.
I have a couple of tips for those as newbies as me trying to get this together on 13.10 :

1) installing SAMBA separately with apt-get after OS-installation seemed to be better than installing it as an option when installing the OS. I don't know exactly WHAT it was, but it behaved differently.

2) All the howtos and docs I have read (and tried) for AD/Winbind are a little outdated.
IF you do thing right and in the right sequence, there is NO NEED to fiddle with any of the `/etc/pam-d/` - files. pam-auth-update takes care of everything ! The only exception is perhaps 'common-session' if you want to have a home-directory created automatically for users logging in for the first time from AD.

3) same with Kerberos - use `dpkg-reconfigure krb5-user` in stead of editing /etc/krb5.conf as many papers will tell you to do.

4) Most of the Howtos and documents describing `/etc/samba/smb.conf` are also outdated. Use new format and remember to do `testparm`. The important part of mine looks like this :

```
    workgroup = LUUN
    netbios name = trubadurix

    security = ads
    realm = LUUN.LOCAL
    winbind use default domain = yes
    winbind enum users = yes
    winbind enum groups = yes
    winbind nested groups = yes
    winbind refresh tickets = yes
    template shell = /bin/bash
    template homedir = /home/%D/%U
    domain master = no
    client use spnego = yes
    idmap config *:backend = tdb
    idmap config *:range = 10000-20000
    idmap config LUUN : backend = rid
    idmap config LUUN : range = 1000-20000
    idmap config LUUN : base_rid = 0
    map untrusted to domain = yes
```

5) remember to install `libpam-krb5`, `winbind` (no - SAMBA is not enough even though some of the documentation would lead you to believe that), `libpam-winbind` and finally `libnss-winbind`...