# winbind not working after upgrading to 14.04 (from 12.04LTS)

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, dhcp

Winbind stopped working after I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 (from 12.04 following the automatic upgrade prompt).
This is on a home LAN with my router providing dynamic IP addresses to my machines.
Specifically mount does not recognize my network file server by name, and requires the IP address.
Also I noticed my dhclient.conf file is empty. Is this how it should be?

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the solution on another thread here [Problem with Winbind/Samba](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389039/problem-with-winbind-samba)

Basically I had install (or update?) libnss-winbind

sudo apt-get install libnss-winbind